# variable returning undefined although same variable returned its value previously

Tags: javascript

Hi Im a beginner so please forgive any basic mistakes. I am trying to learn java script online and so its read this and teach yourself I am working through one of the projects and am confused as I have defined a variable called it one and it prints the string then later called it again in another string and it shows it as undefined. here is my code.

```
let userName = 'Steve';

userName = userName ? console.log(Hello ${userName}.) : console.log('Please enter your name');

let userQuestion = 'why are we here';

console.log(You ${userName}, would like to know, ${userQuestion});
```

this all works as I would expect apart from the last line that returns
You undefined, would like to know, why are we here?
I am aware undefined is returned when nothing is set to the variable but the variable is already set and works the first time I have even removed the first instance out and ran it again the issue still happens.
any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You reassign `userName` to the result of `console.log`, which returns nothing…

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning `userName` to the return value of `console.log()` which is `undefined`

Comment: Could you explain to me where as as far as I am aware I have only defined username once
 at username = steve;